# Can you make askubuntu fit on netbook screens?

Tags: feature-request, design

Being a netbook user (Eee PC) I am frequently annoyed by the fact that askubunt doesn't fit on my screen horizontally.

Could this website's maintainer make the website resize correctly?
As Ubuntu is heavily supporting netbooks with ther netbook edition this would be quite logical to me.

See this screenshot as a reference:
[image]

Comment: Is there a standard netbook resolution? I think another interesting factoid to research is how much traffic is from netbooks.

Comment: The default resolution on many netbooks is 1024*600 (16:9). This might definitely not be high priority but scalability is just a quality design feature that is desirable. Hence it would also be interesting to look how it scales on big screens.

Comment: IIRC This site should look fine on 1024 resolution - do you have a screenshot showing what doesn't fix?

Comment: Sure! I added a screenshot to the original post.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the [Stack Overflow 2010 Analytics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/), @JeffAtwood tells us :

> We design for a fixed minimum width of 1024 px [...].

Obviously screen and window widths can be different, especially in your case because of the Unity interface so you are unluckily part of the non-targeted audience.

Can they make askubuntu more netbook-friendly ? Sure.

Will they make it ? I don't know. I'm also not sure if we should consider this request as an askubuntu specific or as a generic stackexchange issue.

Currently you have some solutions :

- Zoom out in your browser (Ctrl + scrolldown, works for Chrome and FF).
- Maybe modify your interface : hiding the left panel, not using Unity (yes, I know, this can't be a really satisfying answer...)

Comment: I think the bug is really with Unity not SE. With the release of Ubuntu 11.04 you will be able to make the Unity Launcher autohide and effectively fix this bug.

Comment: We have control over the design and *can* change the width of the site if deemed so. However, I think as @fluteflute has mentioned this is really an issue with Unity which will be addressed in the up coming releases.